# Python - Range and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, range

```
money_badges = {range(0,100):'Me first dollar',
                range(100,150):'Mo\' money mo\' problems',
                range(150,100000):'So much money :D'}
money = 5
if money in money_badges:
    print('You have been awarded the ' +money_badges[money]+ ' badge')
```

I'll try to keep this short. I want to try and allow the player to earn the badge "Me first dollar" when he or she has 0-99 (or any of the other ranges) money.
This is the method I have been trying, however, I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it, as I am still learning how to code.

This is my first post on the site, I hope everything is formatted correctly.

Comment: I would store the min max values as key of tuples and not enumerated ranges, given the limited number of badges a set of if statements would run better

Comment: Can you use a list as a key in a Python dictionary? I thought keys had to be immutable.

Comment: @bsoist: In Python 2, range returns a list, but in Python 3, it's actually closer to xrange in Python 2. The [xrange sequence is immutable in Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange) and I would imagine that transferred to Python 3 making range return an immutable. Thus it might be good to add a Python 3 tag.

Comment: @Nuclearman thanks, I assumed perhaps that was the case, but your are right - it might be good to tag it

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this (as a function with a [demo](http://repl.it/Pgi)):

```
money_badges = {(0,100):'Me first dollar',
                (100,150):'Mo\' money mo\' problems',
                (150,100000):'So much money :D'}

def AwardBadge(money):
    for badge in money_badges:
        min, max = badge
        if min < money < max:
            return money_badges[badge]

print AwardBadge(5)
Me first dollar
print AwardBadge(12345)
So much money :D
```

Comment: If you adjust to handle out of bounds, I'll upvote and delete my answer.

Comment: Well technically it deals with out of bounds by returning `None` (http://repl.it/Pgi/1) was there something more Pythonic?

Comment: It's probably wise to actually use "return None", if there is a meaning to the function returning None.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a function for this?

```
def money_badges(money):
    if money < 100:
        return 'Me first dollar'
    elif money < 150:
        return 'Mo\' money mo\' problems'
    elif money < 100000:
        return 'So much money :D'
    else:
        return 'Say what?'

money = 5
if money in money_badges:
    print('You have been awarded the ' + money_badges(money)+ ' badge')
```